# Android - Any Timer component that allows to use pause,resume

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

I'm using a simple countDownTimer

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         //do things
     }
  }.start();
```

But now, I want to call something like

> countDown.pause(); countDown.resume();

(storing the remaining time and progress this way):

I know that is not possible with CountDownTimer.

How I can use a timer or handler with the **same behaviour of onFinish()** method from CountDownTImer?

Comment: In case that you want to use a CountDownTimer class instead of a Timer, I made a post where I provide a easy solution for this problem, using a CustomCountDownTimer Class which allow you to pause and resume freely.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965624/pause-resume-countdowntimer-android/36965625#36965625

Hope that it can provide you another way to fix your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really good library to do exactly what you want : [**pause-resume-timer**](https://github.com/c05mic/pause-resume-timer)

It is basically a subclass of `Timer`. A really easy to use library. All you need to do is:

```
//This creates a timer which ticks every 2 seconds, and runs for 20 seconds.
Timer twoSecondTimer = new ExampleTimer(2000l, 20000l);
//Start the timer.
twoSecondTimer.start();
//Pause the timer.
twoSecondTimer.pause();
//Resume the timer
twoSecondTimer.resume();
```